# Create Hive table and import data (.parquet) from HDFS into Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, parquet

I have data (.parquet) in my hdfs (folders with data for each year in which in turn there are folders with months and in each month there is a folder with days and in the package with days there are my .parquet files). I need to create Hive table and import data from HDFS into Hive table. And load data into Kafka using Hive-Kafka integration. How can I do this?

I have Hadoop 3.2.2, Hive 3.1.2, Kafka 2.7, guava-27.0-jre.jar, kafka-handler-3.1.3000.7.1.1.2006-3

Parquet file schema:
{double lng, double lat, double avg_tempr_f, double avg_tmpr_c, string wthr_date}

Comment: The Hive Kafka handler is only a consumer, last I checked... In any case, please edit your question to include your attempts at creating an external table, in parquet format, with partitions for the year, month, day(?) over the HDFS location where you have files